# Fill Whole screen Responsive Height

Tags: responsive-design, resize, height

How would i come across the effect from this website http://www.theqcamera.com or http://plugandplaydesign.co.uk (the video + image at top) so that the image fills the screen on any screen size. Im not sure if this is responsive height but really would like to know how to do it.

Comment: ... In what language? HTML? CSS? Javascript? Coffeescript? Typescript? Java?

Comment: i don't mind just anyway to get it too look and do what those websites listed do

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. The easiest is to use vh (vertical height) in your CSS. A setting of 100vh will make your div be 100% of the height of the screen being used to view the page. Combine this with a background image that is set to "cover" and a 100% width on the domain and you should be good to go.

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="div_1">
           content
       </div>
       <div class="div_2">
           other content
       </div>
   </div>
</body>

.div_1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.div_2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Please note: vh is not supported in IE8. If you need to support IE8 for your project, going with position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; margin: 0; is a slightly more complicated, but more backwards compatible answer.

Comment: can i ask what goes in the content area

Comment: and how does it know the size of the browser (I've never used vh

Comment: Sorry about the super long delay on this. Your content for the two screens worth of stuff goes in the content sections. 100vh works with modern browsers to simply determine the height of the browser at the time the page loads. It then uses that height to determine the height of the div you'd like to have fill the height of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

try using height 100% , position absolute , margin 0 auto 
this is how I've made my picture 100% on my website (http://www.dotto.be)

Comment: On my css should I write: .background{ Position:absolute; margin: 0 auto; height: 100%; }

Comment: And html what should I put <div class="background" and nit sure how to di the rest

Comment: in your style sheet you make a class with the same name that you gave to the div so "background"

this is what you should enter in your style sheet :
`.background{
  background: url(assets/images/17.gif);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: top center;
}`

This a short version of what my class looks like

Comment: Css is great but unfortunately the image

Comment: in the css does not load so should i put it in the html instead

Comment: how should my html look sorry for being annoying in my experience I've never done a background like this before.

Comment: so i don't have to bother you again could i use your code but change all the divs?

Comment: I am verry sorry for my late respons, can you maybe show what your site looks like ( structure code) from github or something like that ?

Comment: Sorry as well for my late response, tyhnks for your help because i have done it now but i was wondering how you get your navigation bar to always be right under it no matter the screen is, please could u explain. Thanks @maiteh

Comment: since it is a webpage that has only One page the navigation has a fixed position so it always stays at the top, try this on your navigation:     position: fixed;
    top: 0px;